# Why Visual Studio UML Editor shows 1:1 relationship as two directional one to many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, uml

I have a class:

```
  //ClientCard
 public class KartaKlienta {
        [Required]
        public virtual Klient Wlasciciel { get; set; } //Owner
    }
```

and

```
  //Client
 public class Klient : Osoba {
        public virtual KartaKlienta KartaKlienta { get; set; } //ClientCard
    }
```

I generated Uml diagram and to my surprise it shows 2 one to many relationships: http://s4.postimg.org/iam36ol8d/stack.png ( I can't add picture, as I have less than 10 reputation)

Why it doesn't show sing one to one relationship?

Comment: Because there's nothing in the code for it to know that more than one `KartaKlienta` can't have the *same* `Wlasciciel` value? (And similarly for the other property)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought that Entity Framework takes care to don't let it happen. As it keeps reference integrity, but at the same time I see that this code has no knowledge that EF manages instances of those classes. How should I state in the code that this is strict 1 to 1?

Comment: Added to which, of course, is that they can't be in strict one-one anyway since there must be a point in time when one of them has (just) been created and the other one hasn't (yet)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you, I understand. I would like to rephrase and correct my question. How to express that it suppose to be `(KartaKlienta) [0..1] - 1 (Klient)` relationship?